# Quantum harmonic oscillator as the potential becomes zero

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian

I'm having a question concerning the quantum harmonic oscillator: If, for instance, $\omega\to 0$ the Hamiltonian
$$
\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2\tag{1}
$$
becomes that of a free particle, but the energy eigenvalues don't. Why is there such a distinction between the two cases? I get that intuitively it becomes continuous, however I wasn't able to find a more mathematical way  to make $$E_n\to \hbar^2 k^2/2m\tag{2}$$ in this limit.

Comment: As $\omega \rightarrow 0$ the separation of the energy levels tends to 0, giving you the continuous spectrum of a free particle. Can you explain your issue a little more?

Comment: I get that intuitively it becomes continuous, however I wasn't able to find a more mathematical way  to make $E_n\to \hbar^2 k^2/2m$ in this limit.

Comment: I suppose the reason is simply that you (more or less implicitly) assumed a non-zero (perhaps even positive) $\omega$ in the derivation of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the QHO. Also note that for $\omega=0$, all the harmonic oscillator eigenstates become the zero vector, which by definition is not an eingenstate of any operator.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I think I got it.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: I meant the normalized vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One idea is to put the [QHO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator)$^1$
   $$H~=~\frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{m\omega^2x^2}{2}+\infty \cdot\theta(\frac{L}{2}-|x|) $$
   in a [box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box) of length $L$.
2. On the one hand, well above a threshold energy
   $$ E_{\rm threshold}~=~\frac{m\omega^2L^2}{8} $$
   the energy eigenvalues behaves like a particle in a box
   $$E_n~=~\frac{(\hbar k_n)^2}{2m}, \qquad 
   k_n~=~\frac{n\pi}{L}, \qquad n~\in~\mathbb{N},$$
   which should be compared with OP's eq. (2).
3. On the other hand, well below the threshold energy $E_{\rm threshold}$ the energy eigenvalues behaves like a QHO.
4. Now remove the harmonic potential $\omega\to 0$ and remove the box $L\to \infty$ in such a way that $\omega L\to 0$ so that $E_{\rm threshold}\to 0$.

--

$^1$ Here we assume that $\infty\cdot 0~=~0$.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up on @Tobias's argument, the natural unit of length for this problem is $\lambda=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}}$, and so depends on $\omega$.  Since all solutions are functions of the dimensionless quantity $x/\lambda$, you immediately see you are in trouble if you let $\omega\to 0$ as any solution of the form $e^{-(x/\lambda)^2/2}H_n(x/\lambda)$ behaves badly.  In other words, taking the $\omega\to 0$ limit is delicate business and may not be feasible at all.